# Changing the color of button on click and confirmation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this group of roles for user (as buttons) to be selected as their role in the game. Upon selection the color of button should be changed to grey. but yet, upon clicking the button color changes but then it again becomes blue (it remains Grey in the code attached but inserting in original HTML, it changes back to blue). So the Goal is 1: Upon clicking it should remain Grey  and second thing a confirmation box should pop up to confirm "Are you sure you want

```css
.button1 {
    height:1.5cm;
    width: 4.5cm;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    background-color: #0065bd;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: none;
}

.button1:focus {
    background-color:#585858;
    border-color: #585858;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button1">Brewery 1</button>  
<button class="button1">Distributor 1</button>  
<button class="button1">Retailer 1</button>
<button class="button1">WholeSaler 1</button>
<button class="button1">Brewery 2</button>
<button class="button1">Distributor 2</button>  
<button class="button1">Retailer 2</button>  
<button class="button1">WholeSaler 2</button>
<button class="button1">Brewery 3</button>  
<button class="button1">Distributor 3</button>  
<button class="button1">Retailer 3</button>  
<button class="button1">WholeSaler 3</button>
```

Comment: looks like you need a toggle

Comment: for what reason?

Comment: I understood it like this you would like to change when clicked -> then change to grey -> clicked again -> then change back to blue. 
So isn't it toggling the color?

Comment: no actually, after clicking, it should remain grey

Comment: means if you click 3-4 button they have to remain gray?

Comment: whenever a button is clicked (only one button would be clicked) it would be turned to grey and at the same a confirmation box would appear (to confirm the selected role) and upon confirmation the next page would be rendered. I hope it clears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that the color change is done when the button is focused on. That means that as soon as the focus gets lost, the color go back to the original.

What you could do is to add a class to the button when you click it. After that you can ask for confirmation.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button1");

for(button of buttons){
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.classList.toggle('grey');
    setTimeout(() => confirmOption(event.target), 100);
  });
}

function confirmOption(target){
  if(!confirm('are you sure?')){
      target.classList.toggle('grey');
  } else {
    //your code to send the data and redirect to another page
  }
}
```

```css
.button1 {
    height:1.5cm;
    width: 4.5cm;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    background-color: #0065bd;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: none;
}

.grey {
    background-color:#585858;
    border-color: #585858;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button1">Brewery 1</button>  
<button class="button1">Distributor 1</button>  
<button class="button1">Retailer 1</button>
<button class="button1">WholeSaler 1</button>
<button class="button1">Brewery 2</button>
<button class="button1">Distributor 2</button>  
<button class="button1">Retailer 2</button>  
<button class="button1">WholeSaler 2</button>
<button class="button1">Brewery 3</button>  
<button class="button1">Distributor 3</button>  
<button class="button1">Retailer 3</button>  
<button class="button1">WholeSaler 3</button>
```

**Note:** the `setTimeout()` is used to give enough time for the button to turn grey. WIthout it, the confirm pop-up would prevent the changes.

Comment: That works nicely here, but in original code upon clicking a button, it turns to grey and gain to blue at the same moment (the page seems to be refreshes instantly) :|

Comment: I updated the answer to show where you should put the code to redirect to another page. You shouldn't do any refresh when pressing a button, but only after the confirmation